# Mocking with Scala Self Type / Parfait Pattern

Tags: scala

I am using parfait pattern like the following:

```
trait A {
  def a: Future[String]
}

class B {
  this: A =>

  def get: Future[String] = a
}
```

I would like to create a mocking version of `A` so I can control the result of `def a` using Mockito when testing `B`, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

While testing a class `X` which uses an instance of class `Y`, we generally provide a mocked instance of class `Y`.

Here, Your `B` is  not using any instance of `A`, it expects (forces) that anything extending `B` also extends `A`.

Also, you will notice that your class `B` is kind of incomplete as it is. if you choose to create an instance of `B`,

```
val b = new B
// <console>:13: error: class B cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type B with A
//       val b = new B
```

So. basically whenever you are creating an instance of `B` you have to also provide an implementation of `A`.

```
scala> val b = new B with A { def a = Future.successful("well") }
// b: B with A = $anon$1@11ad095c
```

Notice, how we are free to provided any implementation of A, whenever we are creating any instance of `B`.

You can provide whatever you require for your test cases this way.

So,

```
trait AWithMockedBehaviour1 extends A {
  def a = Future.successful("mocked_1")
}

val b = new B with AWithMockedBehaviour1
```

Comment: Does it mean that for each test of class `B`, i'll need to create a new trait? For example, testing how class `B` handles changing response, how it handles exception, and how it handles normal response then exception, etc. In Mockito, it'd be super simple if I have a mock object, I can just do: `when(mock.a).thenReturn(normal 1).thenReturn(normal 2)`, or `when(mock.a).thenThrow(new Exception)`, etc.

Comment: @ssgao Another choice is to create a partial mock for `B`. This will allow you to `mock` the `method` `a`. And you can just use this partially mocked `B` for testing.

Comment: Yes! that is what I am looking for. Would you mind show me how it can be done?

Comment: mixin requires a trait, not an object, how would I be able to inject this `spy` of `A` into `class B`?

Comment: With mockito `spy`, you can create `partially-mocked` instances which means your class should be a concrete class (which `B` is not). You can not create an instance of `B` and neither can mockito. You will have to mock a concrete class  `C` which `extends` `B with A`. You are using Cake pattern and it is a whole different pattern, it comes with its own restrictions.